# Where are the citatations that zotero or mendeley add to a paper?

Tags: file-management, zotero, mendeley

I have both zotero and mendeley on one system and micorosoft word. I have a large file with tons of refrences added by mendeley. however, I refreshed it by zotero and it messed the whole thing. Undo does not work, where are these citations so I can remove it anyway?

How do these (xml,csl?) file attach themself to the .doc file?

also, I changed some of the inline of citations and everytime I refresh they change.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to consult the support channels of those reference managers for this, but for the basics, and in particular

> How do these (xml,csl?) file attach themself to the .doc file?

Both Zotero and Mendeley store citation information in Word "Fields" (the same thing that would e.g. be used for automatically updating dates, page numbers, or cross-references). What they store their is actually not XML/CSL (that is only part of the actual software) but the citation information--which item you're citing, any page numbers, prefix, suffix, usually its bibliographic information etc.--in JSON format (because the tool that actually formats the citations is in javascript). Unfortunately that means this is exceptionally hard to fix by hand.
For what it's worth you can make Word Fields visible by pressing `alt+F9` and see if there's something obvious wrong.
More generally, [Zotero's advice for debugging broken documents](https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_plugin_troubleshooting#debugging_broken_documents) will apply to Mendeley as well.